# Plotting two variable function by Plot3D

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot two variable functions. This is my problem:

```
f[x_, y_] = x*y
Plot3D[{f[x, y]}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

It doesn't plot anything. Of course if I write directly "x*y" in the option of the command `Plot3D`, I get what I want. But for my code is essential to just call the function without specifying the whole expression of it.

Comment: Nothing wrong here. Restart the kernel and it should work.

Comment: @Daniel Huber: Probably no need to restart kernel, as @Joshua Jesse Bocanegra pointed out... probably evaluating `Clear[f, x, y]` and then evaluating your code once again is enough. (or using `:=` instead of `=`)

Answer (score 2):

You should use ":=" instead of "=" for most functions. My guess is that you have assigned x or y elsewhere in your code. See "SetDelayed" in the documentation.

```
f[x_, y_] := x*y
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
```

[image: Output of f[x,y]]

Comment: Actually, `Set` and `SetDelayed` work equally well here.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: Not if `x` or `y` had previously set a value.

Comment: True, but that is not the case as described in the question.